# How to determine which objects / object permissions are applicapble / not applicable for a given profile?

Tags: permissions, profile, object, setup

Some Salesforce objects have own section within `Object Permissions` list in specific profiles, other not. As I know `ObjectPermissions` has `ParentId` field which points to `PermissionSet` associated with profile. Setting `Read` `Create` `Edit` `Delete` `View All` or `Modify All` to true results creation of `ObjectPermissions` record. Otherwise setting all to false results deletion of `ObjectPermissions` record.
In conclusion lack of `Object Permissions` record does not imply that object is not applicable to profile.

How Salesforce "knows" which objects / object permissions to show in setup for a given profile?

Is it possible to write SOQL query to retrive that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this:

[image: Profile and Permission Objects ERD]

taken from the [Profile and Permission Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_profile_permissions.htm) documentation and noticing that a `PermissionSet` can optionally be tied directly to a profile - presumably the permissions are defined for a profile via a hidden `PermissionSet` - I would guess that "yes" you can query the complete access permissions.

**PS**

On the subject of what is the most a Profile can access, that is controlled by the `UserLicense` and this query in the Developer Console returns some rows:

```
select Name, License.Name from PermissionSet order by License.Name
```

with what looks like built-in `PermissionSet` names. But there don't appear to be enough records for that to be the mechanism.

Comment: Helpful, but how to distinguish between all Object Permissions set to false and Object Permissions not applicable for profile? Example - Chatter Free User profile - without any ObjectPermissions and System Administrator profile with Object Permissions defined.

Comment: @gpoluch I don't know if that information is visible; see my PS. Didn't read your question carefully enough...

Comment: Yep @Keith C. User License is the key. Salesforce documentation provides detailed information about Users Licenses and Objects associated with them?